# C++ Flat Array vs Multidimensional Array Memory Footprint

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, destructor

In C++, the `delete[]` operator deletes an array.  It is able to access the length of the array because the allocator keeps track of it.

Does that mean that a flattened one-dimensional array takes up less memory than a multi-dimensional array?

To be more specific, if I allocate `Object** c`, does the allocator store the lengths of both the first and second dimensions, while allocating `Object* c` (but with the same number of elements as the two-dimensional array) only stores one length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
Object **c = new Object*[n];
for (size_t i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
  c[i] = new Object[m];
}
```

then it will typically take more memory than doing this:

```
Object *c = new Object[n*m];
```

for just the reasons you stated.

Every memory allocation has a certain amount of overhead.  In addition to needing to keep the number of elements, there is overhead for the memory allocator itself.  It also takes more memory for all the extra pointers for each row.

Note that it is possible to have a situation where breaking it up would use less memory.  If your heap was fragmented, then finding one large chunk of memory may require allocating more memory from the operating system, whereas if your array was broken into smaller pieces, those pieces may be able to fit in the holes of your fragmented heap.